# Case when in Rank partition By

Tags: sql, window-functions, rank

I've been relearning SQL again but I'm not sure if this code can be done. Can someone please provide feedback or alternative on this case ?

So over all I'm looking into any duplication between a order that was submitted between the same day, different time, same user.

I was thinking for the second step I would rank them to find out if there's another row based on the time and date, to be ranked two?

```
Select * ( including orderDate) 
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY
Customer,
case 
when (Orderstart(Datetimestamp) > OrderEnd(Datetimestamp) and OrderEnd<Orderstart ) AS Rank_Items

From FirstStep
```

This is just ranking everything now going up to 500+ ranks.

Sample Data

[image: Sample]

Desired Result:

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  How do you identify the date and time?  What is `orderend` and `orderstart`?

Comment: OrderEnd - Date timestamp of a customer ordering "completing" the order"
While OrderStart is a date timestamp of a customer ordering the order. 

essentially I'm trying to find any double orders that might've happen in the same day from 13:00-15:00 from one specific customer.

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results.  Your question isn't clear.

Comment: I have edited it now

Comment: Bumping this thread

Answer (score 0):

I would use `row_number()` to get identify multiple orders by the same customer on the same date:

```
row_number() over (partition by customer, cast(orderdatetime as date) order by orderdatetime)
```

The cast-to-date might vary by database.

This enumerates the orders for a customer on a given date, which seems to be what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - The main goal of my ranking is to literally find a duplicate from "Steve" who started an order from 14:50 and ended at 15:15. But Steve, also made a valid order from 14:55-15:00..